# Do musicians read musical notation "by accident"?

Tags: notation, sight-reading

I was looking for wether this had adready been asked somewhere, but -to my surprise- people don't even question why we read words even if we "don't try" to read them. The most similar question I found to it was [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/33w4m3/when_i_look_at_a_word_why_do_i_automatically_read/?sort=top) on Reddit, which is quite forgotten by the community.

So, my question is:

Similar to how we read written natural languages effortlessly, sometimes even unconciously,

1. Do you musicians find yourselves reading musical notation just by looking at it even by "mistake"?
2. What do you guys think about when you do? Maybe the sound of the piece, the execution on your instrument or something else.

The question arised because I'm starting on piano and I know how to read it even with dynamics and accidentals, it's just too tiresome and stressful for my brain and it takes quite long. So I wanna know if the goal should be to aim for a moment where I can read musical notation **as effortlessly** as I can read written English or Spanish.

Comment: Since this is more a discussion question than a simple Q&A question, please consider posting it in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room). I have some thoughts I'd love to contribute, and I have to imagine others will, too.

Comment: I like this question.  I think it is good if we restrict its scope specifically "what level of musician achieves this level of proficiency, if any?"

Comment: Edward, I have no problem with your proposal, that's esentially the same question. However, it's as open for discussion as the previous one, as Aaron pointed out.

I'll let the moderators decide if the question should be closed or not and, if it's closed, I'll be posting it somewhere else in a discussion board and in the chat link Aaron shared.

I won't be posting it only in that link because that chat is kinda obscure and the answer there will be only useful for me, because it's not too visible.

If it's not against the guidelines of the stack, please share your thoughts on my question.

Comment: I also like the question, but I see the point regarding discussions. Would it shift the focus to an acceptable Q&A question to ask (in a separate question maybe), _how_ to achieve the level of proficiency? What/How to practice to get there?

Comment: IDK what is so opinion based on whether you can read music notation as effortlessly as reading letters and numbers when it is such an easy and empathetic yes, I can do so myself and I'm hardly special in this regard

Comment: If you cannot read music notation effortlessly then I fear you may over-estimate your ability to read music.

Comment: I'm hesitant to edit the title of the question myself but if the OP can focus on whether you can learn to read music as effortlessly as words then that would be better. That question has an objective yes. The title does not seem to fit in with the question posed in the last para.

Comment: IMO it's not the substance but the tone of the question that makes people think it's discussion-oriented. Ignore the word "you" and it becomes a question about musical learning. IMO it passes the test of being able to have a "right answer," especially if the appeal to personal experience is removed.

Comment: Also: This is why you can have a visual joke using only a bit of notated music: https://www.classicfm.com/discover-music/humour/amadeus-cafe-menu-music/

Comment: @AndyBonner - Reminds me of one of the Pokemon Showdown April Fool's sprites purposefully sticking "Megalovania" in sheet music lines (the Lapras-Gmax sprite, whose real version already looks like it has sheet music lines without proper clefs, and since Lapras is already known to sing...).

Comment: I don't have that level of fluency, but the answer is yes, this is absolutely something that exists. When Vetinari in the Discworld novels likes to read music (and doesn't like hearing it played), it's similar to how I prefer reading a book for myself to having someone read it out loud to me, and a real person could have that quirk too. (It's possible that a real person's quirk may have been an inspiration.)

Comment: As for learning, have you ever tried to learn a different alphabet? I was once learning Russian. When I got pissed off with the fact that I was still reading like a dyslexic first-grader, I borrowed a novel from the library (this is easier for me because comprehensibility wasn't that much of an issue, my first language being Slavic as well) and just read it. At first it took me a whole day to get through ten pages or so. By the end, I was reading Cyrilic almost as fast as Latin, though by no means automatically (I still had to decide I was going to read it before it happened).

Comment: So while I can't relate directly, I imagine it's in essence the same - you get more fluent by doing it. The more scores you read, the more fluent you're going to get at it. Not sure of it gets automatic (there might be something about brain development and age) but it sure is going to get easier. And fair warning - I lost my fluency when I wasn't reading any Cyrilic anymore. Now I'm a dyslexic first-grader again. So, don't stop.

Comment: @AgustínNietoGarcía I don't see how it would be a discussion in the restricted version I suggested.  Either certain musicians achieve that level of fluency, or they don't.  It's an objective question with a right answer.  If you edit the question accordingly, I will vote to reopen.

Comment: Compare your starting age with reading words and the number of hours per day spent in school reading with your starting age and hours per day reading music notation. Are they even close to the same? If not, reading music will probably require more effort that reading words.

Answer (score 1):

If I see music notation outside of a regular music context, i.e. on a greetings card, tea-towel, mug, shop display or advertising poster, I will try to read it.

But very often the notation, despite containing musical symbols, doesn't actually make musical sense - there are notes with tails on the wrong side, bars that don't add up rhythmically, notes not beamed correctly, noteheads that have been made 3D and shiny, and so on.

Or the creator has taken correct notation from existing sheet music, but without being able to read it themselves they've mangled it.

As far as the being able to read effortlessly, yes it's possible, but practise is vital.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually a good question for the site since it is more like a poll for experiences, as the question is vague enough that I'd be very surprised with an answer being able to cite actual studies.

That being said, I do superficially scan note images and "read" the music in the terms of melodies in my head rather than anything related to fingering or execution (I am multi-instrumental including singing).  It also annoys me to no end to see artful pictures of a violin draped before a piano score sheet and similar.  I cannot avoid unseeing that kind of nonsense, like I cannot avoid notice how "musicians" in motion pictures who are obviously being paid for their speaking or acting abilities try to pretend they are playing some musical instrument in a manner that defies the most basic properties of the instrument.

It would require a conscious effort *not* to notice.

But that kind reaction is tied to the *execution* of music.  When glancing over a score without a particular intent, it is more the sound/structure that is apparent to me rather than any way of executing it.

Incidentally, I also play (chromatic button) accordion, another keyboard instrument, and when "translating" music into patterns, those patterns are the buttons I traverse. Fingers don't appear in my mind: I guess the playing reflexes are responsible for keeping me from running out of fingers while depressing the patterns I have in mind.

But most of the time, I am thinking more in terms of notes than buttons.

Comment: Just btw if you believe there to be technical problems with a question then that should be addressed in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Learning to read music and learning to read and write is not similar it is virtually the same.

People don't realise it because you where seven years old when you were taught how to read and write and not many people's memories go that far, but the process is virtually identical.

When I started Music Theory training with 9 year-old's I would start them of with the G-Clef. We started on the G above Middle-C. You would then pick notes and we would with great anguish in our harts count towards the notes. You Would write A-B-C-D-E-F-G, on there workbooks and you would tell them that you count forwards when you go up on the staff and backwards when you go down.

And you would have to repeat this hundreds of times (If not thousands). It was a great test of patience, because children would guess the name of the notes and you would have to force them to count it, because no child just wants to do what his/her teachers asks of him/her.

This has parallels in regards to when we go to primary school. No child just knows how to write letters or numbers. They are given stencils with the numbers and letters in them so they can learn to write the letters and numbers by stencil first.

After a while they just know how to write a 'g' and they don't have to think about it anymore. Just like with sight-reading you can tell what a name of a note is by looking at it, but it all comes from counting notes many times.

You also find shortcuts with sight-reading. Lines operate in third. So if you  have the A above the G clef and you want to know the note two lines above, then the line above would be a C and one line above that would be an E. The note on the third ledger line above the G-clef is indeed an E.

Comment: The typical age of text reading learning is about 6, but it often begins much before. Sometimes due to required instruction for a certain culture, but also for context reasons (mostly by parent efforts). Most importantly, some elements that become fundamental for text reading are learnt at various levels and even involuntarily or without "awareness". If sufficient and proper learning input is given to the child (including their living context), they may become more familiar with writing patterns of certain symbols (no matter if they're latin letters, ideograms or musical notes).

Comment: This results in an easier learning experience and, to some extent, easier learning of *different* or complex writing systems. That's why children are able to read most non latin characters at the age of ten, even if those writing systems are way more complex: consider Japanese children having a vocabulary of *thousands* of kanji ideograms (and the same goes for similar extended writing systems). It mostly falls into the ability to establish meta-pattern recognition (shapes and contexts) at younger age. It's not so different than seeing a `×` symbol, or the red color.

Comment: Even for a young adult, learning those languages may be extremely difficult, if not almost impossible for an acceptable level, unless their childhood experiences created neural patterns compatible with those graphical structures. It's one of the reasons for which learning music as an adult is potentially more difficult: learning unfamiliar (and possibly "incompatible") patterns requires much more efforts, unless the initial learning structures achieved at young age allow so. Even ignoring verbal language patterns, it's easier for a Japanese to learn Chinese than it would be for a German.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if 'by accident' is quite right!  But, yes, just as most people can scan a line of text and grasp the meaning without examining every word, an experienced musician can glance at a line of music and absorb 'how it goes'.

This is connected with the facility many pianists have to 'play the music, not the notes' when confronted by an over-complex score (or an over-simplified song copy!)

Or, perhaps the ones who can't do this, can't do the first thing either?   I can only really speak for me.